# how to get contents from minidom parsing using python?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, minidom

I have a xml like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<item>
<title>Images disappeared in Opera when JavaScript is enabled</title>
<link></link>
<pubDate>Wed, 28 May 2014 16:43:54 GMT</pubDate>
<description><![CDATA[I can't use forums normally in Opera browser since few hours ago. I have to turn Javascript off to see them (then like buttons and rich text editor don't work, of course.) Please fix it. JS  must be causing errors...]]></description>
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div>I can't use forums normally in Opera browser since few hours ago. I have to turn Javascript off to see them (then like buttons and rich text editor don't work, of course.)<br />
<br />
All images are missing. Everything works fine in Chromium.<br />
<br />
Please fix it. JS  must be causing errors in other browsers as well. (Opera counts as much as 15% user base in Russia.)<br />
<br />
In Dragonfly debugger, I see<br />
<br />
not sure it's related.</div>
]]></content:encoded>
</item>
```

To get contents inside description tag i used code like this,

```
contents = item.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].firstChild.data
```

But i want to know how to fetch data inside following tag,

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div>I can't use forums normally in Opera browser since few hours ago. I have to turn Javascript off to see them (then like buttons and rich text editor don't work, of course.)<br />
<br />
All images are missing. Everything works fine in Chromium.<br />
<br />
Please fix it. JS  must be causing errors in other browsers as well. (Opera counts as much as 15% user base in Russia.)<br />
<br />
In Dragonfly debugger, I see<br />
<br />
not sure it's related.</div>
]]></content:encoded>
```

I don't know xml parsing please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xml.dom.minidom: Getting CDATA values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597058/xml-dom-minidom-getting-cdata-values)