# Figuring out where CDATA is in lxml element?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I need to parse and rebuild a file format used by a parser which speaks a language that can only charitably be described as XML. I realize that standards-compliant XML doesn't care about either the CDATA or the whitespace, but unfortunately this application demands that I care about both...

I'm using `lxml.etree` because it's pretty good at preserving CDATA.

For example:

```
s = '''
<root>
  <item>
     <![CDATA[whatever]]>
  </item>
</root>'''

import lxml.etree as et
et.fromstring(s, et.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False))
item = root.find('item')
print et.tostring(item)
```

This prints:

```
<item>
    <![CDATA[whatever]]>
  </item>
```

`lxml` has exactly preserved the formatting of the `<item>` tag... great!

The problem is that I don't have any way to tell exactly where the CDATA begins and ends within the text of the tag. The property `item.text` gives no indication of exactly which part of the text is wrapped in CDATA:

```
item.text
 ==> '\n     whatever\n  '
```

So if I modify it, and try to spit it back out as CDATA, then I lose the locations of the whitespace:

```
item.text = CDATA('foobar')
et.tostring(item)
 ==> '<item><![CDATA[foobar]]></item>\n'
```

Clearly, `lxml` "knows" where the CDATA is located within the text of a node, because it preserves it with `node.tostring()`. However, I can't figure out a way to introspect which parts of the text are CDATA and which aren't. **Any advice?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about `lxml`, but with `minidom` you can change the CDATA section and preserve the surrounding whitespace, as `CDATASection`s are a separate node type.

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> data = minidom.parseString(s)
>>> parts = data.getElementsByTagName('item')
>>> item = parts[0]
>>> item.childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n     '">, <DOM CDATASection node "u'whatever'">, <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">]
>>> item.childNodes[1].nodeValue = 'changed'
>>> print item.toxml()
<item>
     <![CDATA[changed]]>
  </item>
```

See [xml.dom.minidom: Getting CDATA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597058/xml-dom-minidom-getting-cdata-values) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will take a crack at a `minidom` conversion if I can't fudge the output enough to get the right results with `etree`. (And thus another layer of this creaky, kludge is born...)