# CDATA getting stripped in lxml even after using strip_cdata=False

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I have a requirement in which I need to read a XML file and replace a string with a certain value. The XML contains CDATA element and I need to preserve it. 
I have tried using parser and setting strip_data to false. This is not working and need help to figure out a way to achieve it.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

parser1 = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)

with open('testxml.xml', encoding="utf8") as f:
tree = ET.parse(f, parser=parser1)

root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.getiterator():
    try:
        elem.text = elem.text.replace('Bundled Manager 2.2(8b)', '123456')
    except AttributeError:
        pass

tree.write('output_new8.xml', xml_declaration=True, method='xml',  encoding="utf8")
```

Below is the Sample xml:

---

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!-- Copyright   (c) 2015 Moto Company, LLC. All rights reserved. Moto Confidential/Proprietary Information -->
<Benchmark>
       <status date="2013-03-11">draft</status>
    <title>Logitech TMM block(TM) System 300 Release Certification Matrix</title>
    <description>Random discription</description>
    <version time="2013-03-05T15:20:20.995-04:00" update="">3.0.0-2017.03.00</version>
        <model system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default"/>
    <Profile id="xccdf_com.Moto_profile_release_4.0.21">
        <status date="2016-03-30">draft</status>
        <title>RCM 4.0.21</title>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>Moto Vblock System 300 Release 4.0.21</p>
<ul><li> TMM VNX OE for File was updated to 7.1.79.8.</li>
</ul>]]>
</description>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vision_content_version">3.0.0-2015.07.00</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vision_version">3.0.0</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vplex_version">5.3.0.03.00.04</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_powerpath_version">Bundled Manager 2.2(8b)</set-value>       
        <select idref="xccdf_com.Moto_rule_vnx_version" selected="true"/>
        <select idref="xccdf_com.Moto_rule_vplex_version" selected="true"/>
    </Profile>
</Benchmark>
```

The output of the code is shown below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2015 Moto Company, LLC. All rights reserved. Moto Confidential/Proprietary Information --><Benchmark>
    <status date="2013-03-11">draft</status>
    <title>Logitech TMM block(TM) System 300 Release Certification Matrix</title>
    <description>Random discription</description>
    <version time="2013-03-05T15:20:20.995-04:00" update="">3.0.0-2017.03.00</version>
        <model system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default"/>
    <Profile id="xccdf_com.Moto_profile_release_4.0.21">
        <status date="2016-03-30">draft</status>
        <title>RCM 4.0.21</title>
        <description>&lt;p&gt;Moto Vblock System 300 Release 4.0.21&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt; TMM VNX OE for File was updated to 7.1.79.8.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
</description>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vision_content_version">3.0.0-2015.07.00</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vision_version">3.0.0</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_vplex_version">5.3.0.03.00.04</set-value>
        <set-value idref="xccdf_com.Moto_value_powerpath_version">123456</set-value>        
        <select idref="xccdf_com.Moto_rule_vnx_version" selected="true"/>
        <select idref="xccdf_com.Moto_rule_vplex_version" selected="true"/>
    </Profile>
</Benchmark
```

>

As you can see , CDATA section is stripped. 
It will be great if someone can help me here.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are doing

```
elem.text = elem.text.replace('Bundled Manager 2.2(8b)', '123456')
```

which replaces the CDATA with a normal text node.

The [documentation](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata) states

> Note how the `.text` property does not give any indication that the text content is wrapped by a CDATA section. If you want to make sure your data is wrapped by a CDATA block, you can use the `CDATA()` text wrapper.

Therefore, if you want to keep the CDATA section, you should only assign to `elem.text` if you are modifying it, and instruct lxml to use a CDATA section:

```
if 'Bundled Manager 2.2(8b)' in elem.text:
    elem.text = ET.CDATA(elem.text.replace('Bundled Manager 2.2(8b)', '123456'))
```

Due to how the `ElementTree` library works (the entire text and cdata content is concatenated and exposed as a `str` in the `.text` property), it's not really possible to know whether CDATA was originally used or not. (see [Figuring out where CDATA is in lxml element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171791/figuring-out-where-cdata-is-in-lxml-element) and [the source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/8ab51504249204e8bb3516b41d859c9c8adaab38/src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx#L1019-L1035))

Comment: Thank you Keith , your explanation makes sense. I will try the solution and let you know.

Comment: @Keith, I'm curious if you can tell if CDATA has been used when it's empty? `<![CDATA[]]>`. My hunch is you can since lxml returns an empty string whereas an empty node normally returns `None`.

Comment: @MarcelWilson my tests confirm your hunch :) even with `remove_blank_text=True`, the CDATA stays.