# Get element's text with CDATA

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

Say, I have an element:

```
>>> el = etree.XML('<tag><![CDATA[content]]></tag>')
>>> el.text
'content'
```

What I'd like to get is `<![CDATA[content]]>`. How can I go about it?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549514/cdata-getting-stripped-in-lxml-even-after-using-strip-cdata-false) may help

Comment: I imagine that `"<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(el.text)` is not an option?

Comment: @SebastienD Not an option, I want to make sure in a test that content is wrapped in CDATA.

Comment: ok, posted an answer that checks that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `el.text`, that's always going to give you the plain text `content`.

To see the serialized element try `tostring()` instead:

```
el = etree.XML('<tag><![CDATA[content]]></tag>')
print(etree.tostring(el).decode())
```

this will print:

```
<tag>content</tag>
```

To preserve the CDATA, you need to use an [`XMLParser()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parser-objects) with [`strip_cdata=False`](https://lxml.de/api.html#cdata):

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)

el = etree.XML('<tag><![CDATA[content]]></tag>', parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(el).decode())
```

This will print:

```
<tag><![CDATA[content]]></tag>
```

This should be sufficient to fulfill your "*I want to make sure in a test that content is wrapped in CDATA*" requirement.

Comment: To be more precise, `re.sub(r'^<[^>]+>|</[^>]+>$', '', etree.tostring(el, with_tail=False).decode())`. At least I see no better way.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using BeautifulSoup and look for `CDATA` instances:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<tag><![CDATA[content]]></tag>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
"<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, bs4.CData)))
```

**Output**

```
<![CDATA[content]]>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `lxml`? Or does any testing library use `beautifulsoup`? I'd like to avoid mixing different libraries? Although I must admit, the one I'm using right now ([xmlunittest](https://pypi.org/project/xmlunittest/)) is of questionable quality. I'm not good at writing tests yet, but so it seems.